# machine learning: convention for ( row, column ) variables ( truth, prediction ) in a confusion matrix?

Tags: confusion-matrix

in machine learning, is there an established convention for which are the ( row, column ) variables ( truth, prediction ) in a confusion matrix?

in statistics it has long been true that the convention is that the columns are truth (e.g., the actual disease status) and the rows are predictions (e.g., the results from a screening test)

it would be both confusing (pun intended) and dismaying if the two fields had opposite conventions

thanks and best wishes, david draper